# Python pandas printing correct dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading from a csv-file, and have the current values in my dataframe, where width and height is min and max value.

```
name     width       heigth
apple    [10, 20]    [15, 18]
```

And now i want to split and format the columns and print them:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['width'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['width-min', 'width-max'])
pd.DataFrame(df['height'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['height-min', 'height-max'])

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

My problem is that it stills print:

```
name     width       heigth
apple    [10, 20]    [15, 18]
```

Whereas I want it to print:

```
name     min-width   max-width   min-height   max-height
apple    10          20          15           18
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both of those things RETURN new dataframes.  They do not modify the existing one in place.

Comment: What do I have to modify the current one?

Comment: you do not need to modify your original df, you can put a reference to a "modified version" by ''' new_df = pd.Dataframe(...) ''', then "new_df" points to the df you created, while the old is kept as it is. or just do ''' df = pd.DataFrame(df....) to overwrite.

Comment: But if I do that it only returns the two columns, not all of them. Like:

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['width'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['width-min', 'width-max'])

only print width-min, width-max. whereas I want all 4 columns

Comment: That is because you build two new dataframes, which means one for wifth attribute and one for height attribute. So 2 dfs for 2 attributes concerning height and width in separate "tables". Therefore you overwrite twice, which means you only have access to the latter df. you can store the two separately, lets say in df_1 and df_2. Then you use the "merge" function of dataframes on the common index in order to combine all four columns in a single dataframe. Checkout merge function here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you ,

```
a = {"name":['apple'],
     'width': ['[10, 20]'],
     'heigth': ['[15, 18]']}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df['min-width'], df['max-width'] = df['width'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', ')[0]), \
                                   df['width'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', ')[1])

df['min-height'], df['max-height'] = df['heigth'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', ')[0]), \
                                   df['heigth'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', ')[1])

df = df.drop(['width','heigth'],axis=1)
```

The `df` will be,

```
    name min-width max-width min-height max-height
0  apple        10        20         15         18
```

please let me know if that helps you !! Also, I am open to optimized suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

You do not save the resulting df.
You need to assign the modified df to a new variable or overwrite the original.

EDIT:

```
#create a separate df for each split operation (height and width separately)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df['width'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['width-min', 'width-max'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df['height'].str.split(',').tolist(), columns=['height-min', 'height-max'])

# join the two dataframes on a common index or column
pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=["enter common column here"])
```

Comment: How can i overwrite the original one?

Comment: I commented above.